# react-mapbox-gl _onClickGeolocate() call with setTimeout to request location automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, settimeout, mapbox-gl

I am using the following code to add the `GeolocateControl` to my react-mapbox-gl map in react.

I need to automatically call the method `_onClickGeolocate` method using `setTimeout()` to request the user location automatically upon loading the page.

How would I be able to achieve this ?

```
import { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { accessToken } from "../../api/tokens/mapbox";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

class Locater extends Component {
  static contextTypes = { map: PropTypes.object.isRequired };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.context;

    map.addControl(
      new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        accessToken,
        positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        trackUserLocation: true
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Locater;
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this create a new variable for the `geolocate` control, and pass this newly created variable into your `map.addControl` method.

Following this bind the `geolocate._onClickGeolocate` method to the `geolocate` variable within the `setTimeout()` method.

This will automatically call the `_onClickGeolocate` method for you.

```
import {Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { accessToken } from "../../api/tokens/mapbox";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

class Locator extends Component {
  static contextTypes = { map: PropTypes.object.isRequired };


  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.context;

    const  geolocate  = 
      new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        accessToken,
        positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        trackUserLocation: true
      })

    map.addControl(
      geolocate
    );
  setTimeout(geolocate._onClickGeolocate.bind(geolocate), 5)
  }


  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Locator;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very late, but the following will work:

```
let geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
      positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      },
      trackUserLocation: true,
    });
    map.addControl(geolocate);

map.on("load", function () {
      geolocate.trigger();
    });
```